# Object to hexagons

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, topology

I want to change a model into hexagons. looking for a similar result:

[image]

Is there a way to rearrange the topology of any object to be made out of hexagons, sort of like the triangulate modifier but to hexagons instead of triangles?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have tris you can use dual mesh.

Starting with triangular faces such as an icosphere some tutorials use the dual mesh node to change the faces into hexagons.

[image]

In your example picture, a second step might be to split the edges of the faces, scale the elements, and then extrude them.

[image]

If we want to separate the extruded hexagons later, there is one problem, which is that they are not capped on both sides.  This can be solved by adding another node to create the missing face:
[image]
Another couple examples, using the triangulate node to change the mesh first:

[image]

This method does not always work, depends how evenly the triangles are stacked.  In an Icosphere it works very well.

I realize a more advanced answer or node group is out there, but this is a simple trick.

Comment: Is there a way to separate each hexagonal to be a different object?

Comment: Well, I have two ideas about that.

Comment: You could apply the geometry node modifier.  Then,  select the whole object, and press P to separate by "loose parts".  This would make each hexagon a completely separate object.   This would work if your tree is "triangulate>dual node>split edges>scale elements>extrude>group output".

Comment: Or, if you want to keep it as one, but track their IDs you could do some research into how the index works in geometry nodes.  There are many related questions.  The user Quellenform has a good answer concerning hexagons.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264036/how-can-i-create-a-hexagonal-structure-with-geometry-nodes