# A way to change the seed value every N frames?

Tags: geometry-nodes, random

Using Blender 3.4.0 Beta
I'm using geometry nodes to instance a honeycomb curve circle on points using a Grid node. It looks like this:
[image]

I've filled the curve to create the face, realized the instances and am extruding the faces up cyclically based off the of the scene time.
[image]

The "cycle" time is 96 frames (4 seconds @ 24fps) to go from flat to full height.
[image]

I'm using a Random Value node set to Boolean to pick the selection. It's all very straightforward. When I change the Seed, I get a different set of random faces to extrude, but I can't seem to change the Seed WHEN I want to.
[image]

The problem I'm having is that I want the Seed value in the Random Value node to change whenever the modulo of the #frame/96 is 0. In essence, the faces retract all the way, and when they rise again, I want a whole different set of faces being extruded.
It seems simple on its face, but I don't see a way of capturing the Seed value being sent when the Boolean is True so that I can keep sending that same value the whole time it's False, until the next True, when it can be updated again. I took out the myriad nodes that were not working for clarity.

Is there a way to do this? I have tried MANY things, but nothing seems to do the trick. Thank you in advance for any guidance! Cheers!

Comment: This may not be quite the solution you'd prefer, but the short answer is maybe to just set the seed and other values to desired keyframes.

Comment: Use a math node to floor the frame number divided by 96 ?

Comment: I mean, yes, manually works, and I consider setting keyframes as manual in this context, because it's just looping ad infinitum

Comment: Gorgious, that worked brilliantly. Simple. That's an answer! Thank you!!! BTW, IDK how to make that an answer 'officially'.

Comment: Comments can't be accepted as answers. @Gorgious needs to post an answer then you can accept it.

Comment: I know this is a part you have solved, but always nice to link related material: [How can I create a hexagonal structure with Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/264036/60486)

Answer (score 1):

Using a math node to floor (or ceil, or round, ...) the frame number divided by 96 will yield a different (incremented) number every 96 frames.

Example with an unrelated usecase :

[image]

[image]