# Remove duplicate faces with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm generating a world made of hexagons with dynamically varying heights.

To improve the performance, I'd like to remove all faces that are duplicates, i.e. that

- are directly facing each other (opposing normals and no distance between)
- have the same face area

I tried around with raycast and compare nodes but not to a satisfying result. Eventually I'd want it to look like below, that all same-height hexagons have no dividing walls, and only those that have variying heights have.
[image: Current Situation]
[image: Target Design]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything manually. thx.

Comment: Hello, have you tried instancing hexagons and then using the extrude node with the Individual Elements checkbox off ?

Comment: @Chris, how do I add a blend file? Sorry, I'm new to this exchange

Comment: Thanks @Gorgius, I just tried that but the "individual" checkbox seems to have no effect.

Comment: @Chris I've uploaded the file here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/lfwrigau9g7amar6uyroe/Hexworld_nodes_36_experimental.blend?rlkey=zz641184bmk57yw193jmk41zk&dl=0

Comment: *"To improve the performance"* - first try with instances. Chances are the performance will be enough. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/264036/60486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility:

[image]

Its made in two times:

Top part of the node tree: merge only the base vertices, then remove vertices that have more than 3 vertex neighbourg and more than four face neighbourgs.

This first result works well but also removes part of hexagons that are isolated by their height.

Bottom part: merge all and remove vertices that have more than 3 vertices and have 3 faces.

Also works well but also removes part of the contour.

So join the two and merge again by distance.

The result is also around 2.8k vertices.

[image]

Comment: lemon's approach seemed more intuitive and it worked on first try, thanks you both for coming up with fantastic solutions. I'm really impressed what geonodes can do with a little bit of fantasy and lots of math :P bravo!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this setup here, although i am not sure whether it is very performant - maybe you try that out, i was too lazy ;)

[image]

result:

Faces shrink from 3.8k to 2.8k

visualized faces which were deleted:

[image]

Hope it helps.